# Spacing in Email

Tags: image, email, spacing

I have a web version that's displaying fine. When I send a test email, it shows unwanted spacing between the images. I tried changing the the padding and margin , but nothing's working. Why is it doing that?

https://jsfiddle.net/tantalizea/r49oqbjj/

[image: Spacing appears like this. It should not have spacing to make the email appear as one image.]

CSS:

```
a,
body,
div,
img,
span,
table,
td,
tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a {
  color: #231F20;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none
}

a[href^="x-apple-data-detectors:"] {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

area {
  outline: none
}

body {
  font: normal 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #231F20
}

img {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px
}

#preheader {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  color: transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0px
}

.desktop {
  display: table !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

tr.desktop {
  display: table-row !important
}

td.desktop {
  display: table-cell !important
}

img.desktop {
  display: inline !important
}

.mobile {
  display: none !important
}

.break {
  display: inline !important
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    width: 97.5%
  }
  .desktop,
  tr.desktop,
  td.desktop,
  img.desktop {
    display: none !important
  }
  .mobile {
    display: table !important
  }
  tr.mobile {
    display: table-row !important
  }
  td.mobile2 {
    display: table !important;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center !important
  }
  td.mobile {
    display: table-cell !important
  }
  .break {
    display: none !important
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none !important
  }
  .no-border {
    border: none !important
  }
  .smaller {
    font-size: 200% !important
  }
  .smaller2 {
    font-size: 100% !important
  }
  .center {
    text-align: center !important
  }
  .margin {
    margin: 0 auto
  }
  .image {
    width: 100px !important
  }
  .width-100 {
    width: 100% !important
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body style="background:#FFF; color:#858585">
  <div id="preheader" style="display:none; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; color:#878787; color:transparent; height:0; width:0; font-size:0px;">Tuesday, March 7, 2017 | 9840 International Drive, Orlando, Florida | Booth #613</div>
  <!-- /div#preheader -->
  <div class="container" style="margin:0 auto; max-width:600px">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="container" style="margin:0 auto; max-width:600px">
      <tr class="bronto">
        <td height="20"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="bronto">
        <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 68.75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">Is this email not displaying correctly? <a href="%%!message_url%%" style="font:bold 100%/6mm Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; text-decoration:none">Try the web version</a>.</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td height="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="35" class="desktop">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="center">
                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="bottom" width="76%"><span style="font:normal 300% Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; color:#56565a; line-height:100%" class="smaller"><strong><em>You're Invited!</em></strong></span></td>
                          <td style="text-align:right" width="24%"><img src="http://www.kravetcontract.com/email_blasts/tipin.png" alt="KK" style="max-width:144px; width:100%" /></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="35" class="desktop">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <!--<tr class="mobile">

                                            <td class="mobile">

                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%" class="mobile">

                                                    <tr class="mobile">

                                                        <td height="20" class="mobile"></td>

                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr class="mobile">

                                                        <td align="center" class="mobile"><span style="font:normal 200% Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; color:#57565b;" class="mobile"><strong><em>You're Invited!</em></strong></span></td>

                                                    </tr>

                                                </table>

                                            </td>

                                        </tr>-->
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="20"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><img src="http://www.kravetcontract.com/email_blasts/newh-2017/top.jpg" alt="Top" style="max-width:600px" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td align="left" valign="middle" class="desktop" width="78"><img src="http://www.kravetcontract.com/email_blasts/newh-2017/left.jpg" alt="Left" style="max-width:78px" /></td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 100% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#101011; letter-spacing:1px">PLEASE JOIN</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><img src="http://www.kravetcontract.com/email_blasts/BDNY2016/logo.png" alt="kravetcontract" style="max-width:280px" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 100% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#101011; letter-spacing:1.5px">AT THIS YEAR'S</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><img src="http://www.kravetcontract.com/email_blasts/newh-2017/newh_logo_2.png" alt="NEWH" style="max-width:192px" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle"><span style="font:normal 100% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#101011;letter-spacing:1.5px">MARCH 7, 2017 AT 12PM-6PM<br />
                                                                    BOOTH #613</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle"><span style="font:normal 81.25% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#101011; letter-spacing:1.5px">9840 International Drive<br />
            Orlando, Florida</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 100% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#101011; line-height:21px; letter-spacing:1.5px">We look forward to seeing you.</span></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td align="right" valign="middle" class="desktop" width="78"><img src="http://www.kravetcontract.com/email_blasts/newh-2017/right.jpg" alt="Right" style="max-width:78px" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><img src="http://www.kravetcontract.com/email_blasts/newh-2017/bottom.jpg" alt="Bottom" style="max-width:600px" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#56565a">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" align="center" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#56565a"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/9840+International+Dr,+Orlando,+FL+32819/@28.4234728,-81.4662839,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88e77e36c55bc137:0xf5a03296c84a146e!8m2!3d28.4234728!4d-81.4640952?utm_source=directions&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=newh-2017" style="font:normal 75% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background:#56565a; line-height:21px; padding:5px;letter-spacing:1.5px">GET DIRECTIONS <strong style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;">&#9658;</strong></a></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="20"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/one-family.gif" alt="One Family. Ninety-Eight Years." border="0" style="border:none; width:100%" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 150% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585"><span style="font:normal 87.5%/4mm Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">@</span>kravetinc</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="http://www.instagram.com/kravetinc?utm_source=instagram&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=newh-2017"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/instagram.gif" alt="Instagram" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/kravetinc?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=newh-2017"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/facebook.gif" alt="Facebook" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/kravet?utm_source=pinterest&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=newh-2017"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/pinterest.gif" alt="Pinterest" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://www.twitter.com/kravet?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=newh-2017"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/twitter.gif" alt="Twitter" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a>
              </td>
              <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://www.houzz.com/pro/kravet/kravet?utm_source=houzz&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=newh-2017"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/houzz.gif" alt="Houzz" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="http://www.e-designtrade.com?utm_source=edesigntrade&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=newh-2017" style="font:normal 112.5% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">e-designtrade.com</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585"><a href="http://www.kravetcontract.com?utm_source=kravetwebsite&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=newh-2017" style="font:bold 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">KRAVET&reg; INC</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="http://www.kravet.com/services/contact?utm_source=contact&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=newh-2017" style="font:bold 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">CONTACT US</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="http://www.kravet.com/about%20us/privacy%20policy?utm_source=privacy&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=newh-2017" style="font:bold 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">PRIVACY POLICY</a></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><span style="font:bold 75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">Exclusively Available Through Interior Designers</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="bronto">
        <td align="center"><span style="font: normal 68.75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #858585;" xml="lang">This email was sent to %%!contact_email%% by %%!account_organization%%</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="bronto">
        <td align="center"><span style="font: normal 68.75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #858585;" xml="lang">%%!account_address1%% | %%!account_city%%, %%!account_state%% %%!account_zip%%</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="bronto">
        <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 68.75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585"><a href="%%!forward_url%%" style="font:normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; text-decoration:underline">Forward to a friend</a> | <a href="%%!manage_url%%" style="font:normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; text-decoration:underline">Manage Preferences</a> | <a href="%%!unsubscribe_url%%" style="font:normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; text-decoration:underline">Unsubscribe</a></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- /table.container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /div.container -->
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe also add an image of what your seeing when you send the email. Might need a bit more context in order to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Image added. What it should look like is as if it were one image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using display block on all images.

```
style="display:block;"
```

This is a must have on all images.

Cheers

Comment: Another person told me this and it solved the issue. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

To be quite honest, I actually love the way it looks haha.

But I believe your issue is the img. It's based on the width. The aspect ratio makes the height smaller then the size of the table row. This is probably not the best way to fix it, but after going through a bunch of css changes I couldn't get it to work any other way:

On the specific images. Set the `img` style to be moved 4 px down:

`transform: translateY(4px);`

Bottom image, 4 px up:

`transform: translateY(-4px);`

Ex:
Bottom:

```
<img src="http://www.kravetcontract.com/email_blasts/newh-2017/bottom.jpg" alt="Bottom" style="max-width:600px;transform: translateY(-4px);">
```

Should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Great idea!

I tried it, but it messed up the regular view and still didn't work on the test send. It's so frustrating!

Comment: @Tantalizea I tried fiddling with some more CSS but couldn't come up with a solution. Definitely a challenging problem !